# Bath command file path format

Tags: html, batch-file, batch-processing, spring-batch-admin

If i use `%%~fI` in `FOR` command it returns with below format of file path `C:\Users\Girish\Pictures\03\302.jpg`. Is there any batch command that returns the file path in below format `file:///C:/Users/Girish/Pictures/03/test/302.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation. something like this;

```
@echo off
set str=asd\asd
set str=%str:\=/%

echo %str%
pause
```

just be remember if you are working inside the for loops make sure you are using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and access your variables with `!str!` instead of `%str%`